how to use Amazon SCT to connection to an Amazon RDS database?
Apparently, Amazon SCT can be used to compare two schemas for differences.
We have several RDS Postgres databases, using Native postres authentication.
SCT has the option to connect to an RDS database using an AWS service profile, which takes:

AWS access Key
AWS secret Key
Region
A3 bucket folder.

In our AWS portal accounts page, we have have an Access keys page next to the roles we can chose to login with.
If we open this Access Keys page, it gives:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

if I paste the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID value into AWS access Key field, and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY into the AWS secret Key and set the region in the SCT AWS service profile and hit test, it gives:
GENERAL ERROR   com.amazon.sct.exception.SecretManagerException: User xxx profile has incorrect AccessKey
Please review xxx profile credentials
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazon.sct.exception.SecretManagerException: User xxx profile has incorrect AccessKey
Please review xxx profile credentials
in the UI it says: "The test failed.  The connection isn't successful.  The security token included in the request is invalid" and "InvalidClientTokenId"
The crux might be that AWS "Access Key" web page has key, secret and session token, but SCT profile only has key and secret, there doesn't appear to be a way to enter the session token in SCT
note, the only way to access the DBs is via SSH tunnel as its not public, so I'm not sure how SCT will connect without this.
In desperation, I tried downloading the aws cli tool, and running "aws configure", and entered the same key and secret, but this had no effect on SCT, get same error.  It also doesnt have a way to enter the session token.
NOTE: our organization uses MS 365/AD for all authentication and permissions.  Thus we dont have a direct IAM account as such.  If I go to awsapps.com/start/#/?tab=accounts logged in as my MS user, it lists several Roles for different environments, e.g. two roles for stage, two roles for prod etc.  If I click on one of these roles, it "logs me in" to Amazon some how with ability to administer the required RDS databases.  Whilst logged as a role, my account name is something like: assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_DevopsEng_e234242kjsf/myname@myazurebasedorg.com
Any ideas how to fix this?

